# How to reduce the space between line and text in the search view

Tags: android

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:searchIcon="@null"
                android:paddingLeft="-16dp"
                android:paddingStart="-16dp"/>
```

**It looks like this:**
[image]

**How to reduce the space between line and text in the search view in Searchview and reduce the space between text and underline to get result as below:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

to change the thickness

make a drawable file and add this

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
      <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item
    android:bottom="10dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
      <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

and set it to the background in your seachView

new Answer accordion to the new post updating

first change the text size

```
  <style name="AppSearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView" >
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
  </style>
```

then give it a fixed height

android:layout_height="20dp"

and the result is

[image: searchView]

Comment: This just fills the background but doesn't reduce the space

Comment: I have upvoted... but i had modified the question ... i posted the question wrongly

Comment: thank u .. but why u not using an edittext and it will give u more controlls ..so it will be easy for u to edit whatever u want in the UI

Comment: iam gonna update my answer u can change its height and min height and the text size and it will give u exactly what u want